# User rank for a specific time

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I am active on Stack Overflow.

How to get my rank in specific time. ex: What was my overall rank at 1st of August?

The point is to compare it with my current overall rank to evaluate my progress.

Comment: If you don't want to go too far back, then you can work it out with your profile "reputation" tab: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1586924/hasan83?tab=reputation It also depends on how accurate you need this, or if just a rough idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see your rank in the week [including August the 1st](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2015-07-26), using the arrows.

There you are #3707, compared to this week at #107.

As far as I know, there is no way to compare historically without looking at a large number of [user's reputation graphs](https://stackexchange.com/users/1733936/hasan83?tab=reputation).

BTW, on August 1st you had 6976 reputation.

Comment: how did you know that my reputation in 1st of August was 6976?

Comment: @hasan with the reputation graph - 3rd link